# Trying to disable a button but an error popped up

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a help command, but I want to disable it when the embed title is the same as the button label. Except this error pops out:

> C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documents\VSCode\JS\Discord
> Bots\Testing3.JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
> throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
> ^
>
> DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body components[0]: The specified
> component type is invalid in this context components[1]: The specified
> component type is invalid in this context
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documents\VSCode\JS\Discord
> Bots\Testing3.JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documents\VSCode\JS\Discord
> Bots\Testing3.JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
> at async MessageManager.edit (C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Documents\VSCode\JS\Discord
> Bots\Testing3.JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:132:15)
> {   method: 'patch',   path:
> '/channels/956427421073158194/messages/965228940685897748',   code:
> 50035,   httpStatus: 400,   requestData: {
> json: {
> content: undefined,
> tts: false,
> nonce: undefined,
> embeds: [
> {
> title: 'Economy',
> type: 'rich',
> description: null,
> url: null,
> timestamp: null,
> color: null,
> fields: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
> thumbnail: null,
> image: null,
> author: null,
> footer: null
> }
> ],
> components: [
> {
> custom_id: 'econ',
> disabled: true,
> emoji: { animated: false, name: '', id: null },
> label: 'Economy',
> style: 1,
> type: 2,
> url: null
> },
> {
> custom_id: 'info',
> disabled: false,
> emoji: { animated: false, name: '', id: null },
> label: 'Info',
> style: 2,
> type: 2,
> url: null
> }
> ],
> username: undefined,
> avatar_url: undefined,
> allowed_mentions: undefined,
> flags: 0,
> message_reference: undefined,
> attachments: undefined,
> sticker_ids: undefined
> },
> files: []   } }

Code:

```js
    if (cmd === "help") {

        const econ = new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('econ')
        .setEmoji('')
        .setLabel('Economy')
        .setStyle('PRIMARY')
        const info = new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('info')
        .setEmoji('')
        .setLabel('Info')
        .setStyle('SECONDARY')

        const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents([econ, info]);

        let helpMsg = await message.channel.send({
            embeds: [
                {
                    title: "Economy",
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: `\`${cPrefix}bal | balance [user]\``,
                            value: 'Displays your balance or a user\'s balance.'
                        },
                        {
                            name: `\`${cPrefix}dep | deposit <amount>\``,
                            value: 'Deposits a specified amount of cash to your bank.'
                        },
                        {
                            name: `\`${cPrefix}with | withdraw <amount>\``,
                            value: 'Withdraws a specified amount of cash to your wallet.'
                        },
                        {
                            name: `\`${cPrefix}addcoins <user> <amount>\``,
                            value: 'Adds a specified amount of cash to a user. (Administrator)'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            components: [row]
        });

        const collector = helpMsg.createMessageComponentCollector({
            componentType: 'BUTTON',
            time: 60000
        });

        collector.on('collect', async (b) => {
            if (b.user.id === message.author.id) {
                if (b.customId === 'econ') {
                    helpMsg.edit({
                        embeds: [
                            {
                                title: "Economy",
                                fields: [
                                    {
                                        name: `\`${cPrefix}bal | balance [user]\``,
                                        value: 'Displays your balance or a user\'s balance.'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: `\`${cPrefix}dep | deposit <amount>\``,
                                        value: 'Deposits a specified amount of cash to your bank.'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: `\`${cPrefix}with | withdraw <amount>\``,
                                        value: 'Withdraws a specified amount of cash to your wallet.'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: `\`${cPrefix}addcoins <user> <amount>\``,
                                        value: 'Adds a specified amount of cash to a user. (Administrator)'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                        ],
                        components: [row.components[0].setDisabled(true), row.components[1].setDisabled(false)]
                    });
                }
                if (b.customId === 'info') {
                    helpMsg.edit({
                        embeds: [
                            {
                                title: "Info",
                                fields: [
                                    {
                                        name: `${cPrefix}info <user|server> <user: user>`,
                                        value: 'Displays an info of the server or a user'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: `${cPrefix}ping`,
                                        value: 'Displays the current client ping and the database connection'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: `${cPrefix}help`,
                                        value: 'Umm... You used this command'
                                    },
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        components: [row.components[0].setDisabled(false), row.components[1].setDisabled(true)]
                    })
                }
            } else {
                b.reply({ content: 'These buttons are not for you.', ephemeral: true })
            }
        });

        collector.on('end', async () => {
            helpMsg.edit({ components: [row.components[0].setDisabled(true), row.components[1].setDisabled(true)] })
        });
    }
```

Is there anything wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `MessageActionRow` and set everything to disabled. This code is from my bot's help command (discord.js v13.6.0):

```
  let btnraw = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(
    [
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("home").setStyle("SUCCESS").setLabel("Home"),
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("general").setStyle("PRIMARY").setLabel("General"),
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("info").setStyle("PRIMARY").setLabel("Information"),
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("mod").setStyle("PRIMARY").setLabel("Moderation"),
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("fun").setStyle("PRIMARY").setLabel("Fun"),
    ]
  );
  let dbtnraw = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(
    [
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("d_home").setStyle("SUCCESS").setLabel("Home").setDisabled(true),
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("d_general").setStyle("PRIMARY").setLabel("General").setDisabled(true),
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("d_info").setStyle("PRIMARY").setLabel("Information").setDisabled(true),
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("d_mod").setStyle("PRIMARY").setLabel("Moderation").setDisabled(true),
      new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("d_fun").setStyle("PRIMARY").setLabel("Fun").setDisabled(true),
    ]
  );
```

Then you can edit the message to replace the original row like this:

```
helpMsg.edit({components: [d_btnraw]});
```